# mypy で Union の可能性を if で潰したが、エラーが消えない

Tags: python, python3, mypy

python 3 の typing を用いて、以下のようなロジックを書きました。

```
from typing import Union
from decimal import Decimal

Number = Union[int, float, Decimal]


def multiply_numbers(a: Number, b: Number) -> Number:
    if type(a) is float or type(b) is float:
        return float(a) * float(b)
    return a * b
```

しかしこれは、一番最後の行で、以下のエラーが発生します。

```
test.py:10: error: Unsupported operand types for * ("float" and "Decimal")
test.py:10: error: Unsupported operand types for * ("Decimal" and "float")
```

これは、その上で `a` と `b` が float でないことを確認しているので、間違いなく false positive だと思っています。

#### 質問

- python の mypy における Union の、選択肢を場合分けで潰していく処理は、どのように記述するのが正しいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Union 型を具体的な型に場合分けする際には [`isinstance()` を使ってください](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/kinds_of_types.html#union-types)。下のように書くと mypy の静的型検査を通ります。

```
def multiply_numbers(a: Number, b: Number) -> Number:
    if isinstance(a, float) or isinstance(b, float):
        return float(a) * float(b)
    return a * b
```

また、質問文のプログラムは false positive ではありません。[`type()` を使った比較はクラスの継承関係を無視する](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1549801/5989200)ので、たとえば `float` を継承したクラス `MyFloat` を考えると不都合が生じます。下のコードを考えてください。

```
class MyFloat(float):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = MyFloat(3.14)
    print(multiply_numbers(x, 42))
```

`type(x)` は `<class '__main__.MyFloat'>` であり `<class 'float'>` ではありません。しかし `MyFloat` は `float` の子クラスなので、`multiply_numbers()` の引数に `x` を渡すことができます。すると `type(x)` は `float` でないのに中身は `float` という状況が発生し、条件式 `type(a) is float` では取りこぼしが発生します。